# How to extract same rows with positive and negative values

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am trying to get the rows which have some value in one column but positive and negative values in another. Input is the below data frame

```
 data <- data.frame(X = c(1,3,5,7,7,8,9,10,10,11,11,12,12),
                   Y = sample(36476545:36476557),
                   timepoint = c(0,1,0,-0.31,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1)
                   )
```

Output looks something like this

```
X        Y timepoint
4  7 36476557     -0.31
5  7 36476545      1.00
8 10 36476556      1.00
9 10 36476548     -1.00
```

I was looking at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54583558/r-select-all-rows-from-a-dataframe-where-a-value-is-duplicated-one-column-but-ha), but not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After grouping by 'X', `filter` those have both negative and positive 'timepoint' by taking the `sign` of 'timepoint', get the number of distinct elements (`n_distinct`) is 2 (assuming there is no zero)

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   group_by(X) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(sign(timepoint)) == 2)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   X [2]
#      X        Y timepoint
#  <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>
#1     7 36476547     -0.31
#2     7 36476556      1   
#3    10 36476549      1   
#4    10 36476557     -1
```

NOTE: 'Y' values are different as the example was created with no `set.seed`

---

If there is zero as well

```
data %>% 
       group_by(X) %>%
       filter(all(c(-1, -1) %in% sign(timepoint)))
```

---

Or using `base R` with `ave`

```
data[with(data, ave(sign(timepoint), X, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == 2),]
```

---

Or another `base R` option with `table`

```
subset(data, X %in% names(which(rowSums(with(subset(data, 
      timepoint != 0), table(X, sign(timepoint))) > 0) == 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can use `ave` and select groups where there is at least one `timepoint` value greater than 0 and one `timepoint` value less than 0.

```
data[with(data, ave(timepoint > 0, X, FUN = function(x) any(x) & any(!x))), ]

#   X        Y timepoint
#4  7 36476553     -0.31
#5  7 36476551      1.00
#8 10 36476556      1.00
#9 10 36476554     -1.00
```

In `dplyr` this would be

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(X) %>%
  filter(any(timepoint > 0) & any(timepoint < 0))
```